# How to find fonts that don't alias in Windows

Tags: fonts

I've been looking for roman fonts for my website, and I've found that all of them end up looking aliased and jaggy on windows (point your browser at http://tustincommercial.com to see what I mean).

Is there a good way to find fonts what won't alias on the web? I'm not averse to paying for fonts, but obviously I don't want to pay for fonts which aren't going to look good.

Any suggestions or ways of ameliorating this problem will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. It's the result of various properties of the font itself, and won't necessarily even happen at all sizes you might use them. You pretty much just have to try them out and see the results, use something you already see working on some other site, or hope that your webfont service produces screenshot sets [like Typekit](http://typekit.com/fonts/adelle-web)(see the "browser samples" tab).

Comment: Argh. This is what I feared. It's annoying that only typekit (I assume it's only them) produces samples using actual @font-face, instead of rendering as rasters.